# how to get custom post based on custom category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i tried with following code to create custom post and custom category

```
<?php

/*** added for browse plugin custom post - start ***/
add_action('init', 'demoplugin_register');
    function demoplugin_register() {
          $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Demoplugin', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Demoplugin Entry', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New Demoplugin', 'demoplugin'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Demoplugin Entry'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Demoplugin Entry'),
            'new_item' => __('New Demoplugin Entry'),
            'view_item' => __('View Demoplugin Entry'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Demoplugin Entries'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No Demoplugin Entries found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Demoplugin Entries found in Trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
          );

        $slugRule = get_option('category_base');
        //if($slugRule == "") $slugRule = 'category';

        global $paged;

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            '_builtin' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'demoplugin','with_front'=>false),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus'=> false,
            'query_var' => true,
            'paged' => $paged,          
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','excerpt','editor','comments')
        );

        register_post_type('demoplugin' , $args);


        register_taxonomy("demoplugin_entries", 
                            array("demoplugin"), 
                            array(  "hierarchical" => true, 
                                    "label" => "Demoplugin Categories", 
                                    "singular_label" => "Demoplugin Categories", 
                                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'demoplugin-category'),
                                    "query_var" => true,
                                    'paged' => $paged
                                ));  
flush_rewrite_rules( false );   
    }
    function demoplugin_taxonomies() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'plugtag',
        'demoplugin',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'label' => 'Demoplugin Tags',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'plugtag' ),
        )
    );

}
add_action('init', 'demoplugin_taxonomies', 0);

    add_action('admin_init', 'add_demoplugin');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);

    add_action('save_post', 'update_demoplugin');
    function add_demoplugin(){
        add_meta_box("demoplugin_details", "Demoplugin Options", "demoplugin_options", "demoplugin", "normal", "low");
    }
    function demoplugin_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $demoplugin_path_url = $custom["demoplugin_path_url"][0];
        $download_url = $custom["download_url"][0];
        $demoplugin_video_url = $custom["demoplugin_video_url"][0];

        //$demoplugin_excerpt = $custom["demoplugin_excerpt"][0];
        $demoplugin_radiogroup = $custom["demoplugin_radiogroup"][0];
        if ($demoplugin_radiogroup == '') $demoplugin_radiogroup = 'demoplugin_post_action';

/*** added for browse plugin custom post - stop ***/

?>
```

above code has taken from functions.php.**my requirement is list the custom post based on custom category.**

i have tried so many ways to achive my requirement but its fails.

kindly advice on this.

Comment: Please add the wordpress version you're using to your question.

Comment: @hakre  i am using wordpress 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

why is there a `paged` argument? there is none.
`query_var => true` is invalid it should be false or set as a string, I recommend you skip it at all.
Also there is no `singular_label` for the taxonomy there *is* a `singular_name` for the `labels` array

**Read the docs and validate your code first**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: I checked with wordpress url and validate my code and then did the changes given by this URL http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-posts-type-with-custom-taxonomy-wp_query-1 and got the result.